# Using a function in php to create a database connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So really I just want to make stuff easier to read and just create a function where I can call upon the database connection, the below is what i've tried to do to do far.

So far, it doesn't work, it doesn't bring any message at all so presumably it isn't going into the try.

**functions.php**

```
function getDBConnection()
{
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //Set error mode
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'An error occured talking to the DB';
    }
    return $db;
}
```

and then do

**submittest.php**

```
require('functions.php');
getDBConnection(); //return $db


$username = 'donkey';
$password = 'donkey';
$email = 'donkey';
$county = 'donkey';

    try
    {
        //Prepare and execute an insert into DB
        $st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(login,pass,email,county) VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:county)");
        $st->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password, ':email' => $email, ':county' => $county));
        echo 'Success';
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'An error occurred talking to the DB';
    }
?>
```

Comment: What's the question? Is this not working? Have you tested it?

Comment: yeah, it just brings up a blank page, so it doesn't even seem to want to go into the try it seems. also checked to see if its in the database, nothing.

Comment: Are you hard coding the user and pass in the function? Why not passing them as @params to the function? I know it probably has nothing to do with your problem, but it would be easier.

Comment: When you call a function, you generally want to do something with its return value.

Comment: @omega_prime: try turning error reporting on. [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$db = getDBConnection(); //return $db
```